# Why The Background Image Is Not Changing? Note: Its Working Outside The setTimeout, But Inside The (Style) Property Does Not Appear For This Variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let landingPage = document.querySelector(".landingPage"),

    images      = ["url('../Images/001.png')", "url('../Images/002.png')", "url('../Images/003.png')", "url('../Images/004.png')", "url('../Images/005.png')"],

    random      = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);





setTimeout(function(){

    landingPage.getElementsByClassName.backgroundImage = images[random];

}, 1000)
```

```css
.landingPage{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image:url("../Images/001.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="landingPage">                 `The Variable`
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo">JONATHAN</div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="active">Home</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Services</li>
                    <li>Products</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="signUp">SignUp!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Note: Its Working Outside The setTimeout.But Inside, The (Style) Property Does Not Appear For This Variable.So It Works Outside The (setTimeout) Only

Comment: What error(s) are you seeing in your browser's dev tools console? You should be seeing that there is something wrong with landingPage.getElementsByClassName.backgroundImage.  It won't work because you haven't given it a class to search for, and even if you had it won't work because it gives you a collection of elements, not just one. And then if you did get just one it wouldn't work because you have not put .style before the .backgroundImage.

Comment: Consider reformulating your question. Shorten your title, start with the context and update your question. You'll get the upvotes back. more:[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I just do something. You can checkout!

```js
var landingPage = document.querySelector(".landingPage");
var images = [
  "url('https://picsum.photos/401')",
  "url('https://picsum.photos/402')",
  "url('https://picsum.photos/404')",
  "url('https://picsum.photos/403')",
  "url('https://picsum.photos/405')",
];

setInterval(function () {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

  landingPage.style.backgroundImage = images[random];
}, 1000);
```

```css
.landingPage {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="landingPage">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">JONATHAN</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="active">Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Products</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="signUp">SignUp!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```